# How to quickly sum across columns for every permutation of rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, permutation

Suppose I have a `n x k` matrix `X`. And I want to get the sum across the columns, but for every permutation of the rows. So if my matrix is `[[1,2],[3,4]]` my desired output would be `[1+2, 1+4, 3+2, 3+4]`. I produce a MWE example with my first attempt at a solution. I'm hoping I can get some help to reduce the computation time.

My actual problem has `n=160` and `k=4`, and it takes quite a while to run (as of writing this, it's still running).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

n = 4
k = 3

X = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, k))
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df
```

```
   0  1  2
0  2  9  2
1  7  6  4
2  3  7  0
3  5  0  0
```

```
ixi = df.index.tolist()
ixc = df.columns.tolist()

psum = np.array([df.lookup(i, ixc).sum() for i in 
                 itertools.product(ixi, repeat=len(ixc))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.add.outer, df.values.T).ravel()
```